# Word Document Template - Embed after Crystal or SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, crystal-reports, ms-word

I am working with a crystal report that has the first few pages populated with a few fields from the database and the rest of the report has sections of static information (mostly legal terms and conditions).

Now the report runs fine but I am running into a lot of issues when I have to update the terms and conditions text every time there's a change. It may sound easy, but Crystal is extremely finicky when it comes to handling formatting copied over from a Word Document. This makes it extremely difficult to work with.

I am exhausted of ideas trying to make this work, but is there any way to keep that static text independent from the report? Is there anyway to give control of the document to the users so they can change it at will and be stored on the network somewhere that gets called in and embedded onto the report?

It needn't be just a crystal report, it can be a SSRS report as well, it really doesn't matter.

TLDR; Need help embedding contents of a document file in a Crystal/SSRS report that can be sitting out on the network somewhere.

Thanks for the help in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are exporting the report to a PDF you can create just the page with the database information in the report and append the static text as an external PDF files. You will need a 3rd party tool to run the reports.